# Bash completion внутри скрипта

Tags: linux, bash, консоль, администрирование

Есть wildcard:

```
W="hello_*"
```

Есть директория:

```
D="/home/my"
```

с файлами:

```
/home/my/a, /home/my/b, /home/my/hello_world, /home/my/hello_bash
```

Как в bash-скрипте получить в переменную `F` список файлов директории `$D`, подходящих wildcard-у `$W`? Т.е. `F="/home/my/hello_world,/home/my/hello_bash"`. Другими словами, как выполнить bash completion в скрипте?

Comment: `F=$(find $HOME -type f -name "hello_*")`

Comment: `F=$(eval ls "$D/$W")` так же стоит помнить, что использование eval не безопасно и использовать нужно с осторожностью

Comment: @ipatev_nn в чём небезопасность тут?

Comment: @torture в переменной `$W` будет содержаться `;rm ...` что с необходимыми ключами при инициализации строки может привести к нежелательным последствиям. Все же безопаснее будет использовать `find "$D" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$W"`

Comment: @ipatev_nn понял, спасибо

Comment: Экспортируемый код можно запускать как библиотечные функции. Почитайте, как работает bash_completion, там ничего сложного.